# Configuration File in C# default location?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have just created a WPF application and just been wondering where is my app.config file?

I looked in the bin/Debug and bin/Release directories and there is just one file `"WpfApplication1.vshost.exe"` and could not find any app.config file.

All I can do is `Add->New` Configuratin File and this too, doesn't come in debug or Release folder.

Can anyone guide me whether I should manually copy and paste it in the debug or Release Folder?

**So finally: the ANSWER**

If app.config does not exist, then try creating a new one by "Add->New Item->Application Configuration File" and create a file named "App.config". After this, try rebuilding your application, the .config file specific to your project should appear in bin/Debug & bin/Release folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *should* be getting copied into the Debug/Release folders automatically. However, you could try explicitly setting the "Copy to output directory" in the properties to **Copy always** and see if it appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After creating simple WPF project my solution look like this. `App.config` lies there, which is the configuration file itself

[image]

When you build your solution, which in my case is named as WpfApplication1, config file lies at `WpfApplication1.exe.config` in `\WpfApplication1\bin\Debug\` folder. 
[image]

Comment: But, as soon as I Create a new WPF Project, I don't get any app.config file. I had to manually create one by using "Add->New Item->Application Configuration File" and it creates an "App1.config" file and even after building the application, creates no config file in the bin/Debug or bin/Release directory!

Comment: ok, if it names it `App1.config` then another config file is present. Try to click 'View all files' button in the solution and locate it. And try to check 'Copy always' in properties, as @James suggests. In my solution `app.config` has `do not copy` by default, but still it builds as ussual

Answer (score 0):

When you build your application,it automatically gets copies to debug/Release Folder.just look for *.config file in those folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your project you should have a file named `foo.bar.exe.config` in you binary directory. The `app.config` file itself should be visible within your solution directory.