# Getting 'connection to SQL server' error while installing a .exe file of my c# project on client's computer

Tags: c#

I have created software in c#.net which has some database into it. After creating a .exe file it works fine in my system but after installing that
application in another system it gives following error.

Error: A network-related or instant specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connection. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating server/instance specified).

I have tried installing SQL Server and .net framework in client's machine but still, it's not working.

Do I need to install anything else on the client's pc to run my application?

Comment: Well what have you setup as his sql server, and connection string? Are you sure you have access to it?

Comment: You need to install Sql Server, create your database, configure the connectionstring of your application to use this database

Comment: It is likely that your client does not have access to whatever database you were using. Look at connection strings in your config

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string to the database.  The connection string should point to the SQL database the Client has access to.  Most of the time this is not the same as the one you are using while developing.

Comment: how would I add a connection string to my application after creating a .exe file?

Comment: Do I need to add it before publishing ?

Comment: Do a search on ConnectionString in your solution.   It can be in the c# code or in a config file.

Comment: Once you have found it, post it

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="FinalSoftware.Properties.Settings.QPGeneratorConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=VIREN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QPGenerator;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: You should make a backup of your Database QPGenerator,. And restore it on your clients machine.   Then change the source in your connectionstring to point to that restored database.

Comment: Yes but, how would I change the connection string after creating a  .exe file ?

Comment: You can have the config file in the same folder as your exe file.    I have to look it up myself how to do it exactly.

Comment: so, would you tell me after doing some research on it?

Comment: you could define the path where the config file is located in your code, like this : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData ("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "path to config file") . [discribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838619/relocating-app-config-file-to-a-custom-path?lq=1)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194114/configuration-file-in-c-sharp-default-location) page might also help you finding your config file in your client's pc

Answer (score 0):

Change connection string of localhost to IP address of Database PC.

Comment: Can u tell me a step by step process to do it because I'm a beginner at this?

Comment: Yes go to code and change connection string line of localhost to server name. In order to figure out server name or IP address open CMD and write "ipconfig /all"

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to add a connectionstring to your App.config file.

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PRANOYPC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    </connectionStrings>
```

If you are using Windows authentication you can leave Integrated Security = True if not you will have to provide the authentication for the Database.

Also you have to make sure that the Client has access to the database that you are trying to access.